# C++ wchart_t warning: character constant too long for its type

Tags: c++, types, wchar-t

// update 1:

Code Blocks 16.01
GCC 4.9.2
Windows 10

I am trying to understand:

1. What is the use of wchar_t?
2. What is the difference between char16_t and wchar_t?
   I know char16_t is guaranteed to be 16-bit in size, but in this particular case both of them are the same size.
3. What is The proper literals for each char type?

Program goal:

- Printing all the Unicode characters in the range U+0000 to U+FFFF.

// end update 1

When I compile the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void)

{
    std::cout << sizeof(wchar_t) << "\n";
    for (wchar_t ch = u'\u0000'; ch <= u'\uffff'; ++ch)
        std::wcout << " " << ch;

    std::cout << "\n\n\n";
}
```

I got the following warning: "character constant too long for its type" on the line of the for statement.

I ran the program and I got this:[image: output]
.

I searched the net and all what I could find is that wchar_t size is implementation defined, but even so, it is 2 bytes on my system. I think it is big enough.

Q1: Why I got the warning?
Q2: Why there was a few  number of characters in the output? I expected thousands of them.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: and why not use a char16_t instead?

Comment: What compiler, version and OS ?

Comment: Use `u'\uf00d'` for `char16_t` constants and `L'\uf00d'` for `wchar_t` constants.

Comment: Also, your test might fail if every `wchar_t` value is less than or equal to `\uffff`.

Comment: Characters above 256 are not displaying at all (and those characters that are displaying are displaying according to an OEM code page, not Unicode) because you didn't set your locale to display Unicode.  See my answer for a solution.

Comment: Thanks all, I updated the question for more info. Thanks @Davislor for the valuable info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following might work more as intended, displaying every printable codepoint from U+0000 to U+FFFF as Unicode.  Be sure to set your console font to a Unicode font.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cwctype>
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>

#if _WIN32 || _WIN64
// Windows needs a little non-standard magic for this to work.
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <locale.h>
#endif

using std::wint_t;
using std::iswprint;

void init_locale(void)
// Does magic so that wcout can work.
{
#if _WIN32 || _WIN64
  // Windows needs a little non-standard magic.
  constexpr char cp_utf16le[] = ".1200";
  setlocale( LC_ALL, cp_utf16le );
  _setmode( _fileno(stdout), _O_WTEXT );
#else
  // The correct locale name may vary by OS, e.g., "en_US.utf8".
  constexpr char locale_name[] = "";
  std::locale::global(std::locale(locale_name));
  std::wcout.imbue(std::locale());
#endif
}

int main(void)
{
    init_locale();

    for ( unsigned long i = 0; i < 0x10000UL; ++i )
      if (iswprint(static_cast<wint_t>(i)))
        std::wcout << static_cast<wchar_t>(i);

    std::wcout << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Davislor. That is exactly what I am trying to do, however, I tried your code and I got these error: `|23|error: 'stdout' was not declared in this scope|` same for `_fileno` and `_O_WTEXT` in the same line.

Comment: Which compiler and OS?

Comment: This code has been tested on g++ and clang++ on both Linux and Windows, as well as Visual Studio 2017.  It sounds like there's some environment (CygWin?) that sets either `_WIN32` or `_WIN64` but doesn't provide the MS library headers.  If so, I might need to update that test to check for `!__GLIBCXX__` and `!_LIBCPP_VERSION`.

Comment: I ran the code on VS2017 successfully. With the correct code page and the correct font for the console, I can see what I have been looking for. However, I do not know yet why codeblock/gcc cannot do it. Moreover, I tried to use unicode literals inside the code like

Comment: If you save the source file as UTF-8 with a byte-order mark, every modern compiler should be able to read it correctly.  You can then use any characters in string literals, such as `L"étant donné"` At least one compiler I use regularly will have trouble with any other encoding than that.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not working for you on gcc.  It works fine for me on MingW64.  Are you running CygWin?

Comment: Can we chat?  If my `init_locale()` code breaks in your build environment, I'd like to fix it, or at least know what breaks it so I can add a comment.

Comment: Of course, however I never chat before on SO : )   so please feel free to start the chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139098/discussion-between-shadi-and-davislor).

Answer (score 0):

When I run this code it runs fine:

```
int main(void)

{
    std::cout << sizeof(char16_t) << "\n";
    for (char16_t ch = u'\u0000'; ch <= u'\uffff'; ++ch)
        std::wcout << " " << static_cast<char>(ch);

    std::cout << "\n\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks @felipe-lopez. However, I got the same result with the same output. In addition, warning is still there. I updated the question for more clarity. Thanks.